# increment by one ruby string interpolation loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make `data` variable increments by 1 every time it gets collected in the barcode array.

```
 def generate_barcode
    batch_number = params[:batch_number].to_i
    business_partner_id = params[:business_partner].to_i
    current_business_partner = BusinessPartner.find(business_partner_id)

    serial_number = "00000000"
    final_value = current_business_partner.partner_code << serial_number

    barcodes = batch_number.times.collect {
      data = "#{final_value + '1'}" 

      Barby::EAN13.new(data) #currently collecting the same object batch number of times with data value being the same......

    }
  end
```

How do I increment `data` by 1 each time the collect happens?

Comment: What is the question, again?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `times` and `collect`?

Comment: @theTinMan I did for ```collect ``` and thought ```times``` wasn't necessary.

Comment: GIven this is a webapp you should probably defer the generation of the sequence to a DB or some mechanism that has locking else you will end up handling out the same serial_number to different requests

Comment: You asked a similar question the other day, and the selected answer shows an alternate way of doing what you want. I'd recommend trying more before asking. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”

Comment: @theTinMan should I close this question?

Comment: That is up to you. Consider that the answers being provided are deliberately not providing the exact code you need. That is usually done in an attempt to get you to think about this more.

Comment: @theTinMan I will close it. Since this question doesn't help the community and the answers might be found everywhere. Its not very well researched. I can't close it now that it has answers actually so I will leave it.

Comment: @Jngai1297 google "generating database sequence in postgres" replacing postgres with whatever your database is and then defer generation of the serial_number to the function that generates the sequence is in your DB, you can even ensure that the sequence is assigned to your row on creation just like it's done for primary keys, that's better than trying to figure how to do it correctly in the app itself

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a handy helper method for "incrementing" strings, called `succ`/`succ!`. Observe:

```
serial_number = "00000000"

15.times { puts serial_number.succ! }
# >> 00000001
# >> 00000002
# >> 00000003
# >> 00000004
# >> 00000005
# >> 00000006
# >> 00000007
# >> 00000008
# >> 00000009
# >> 00000010
# >> 00000011
# >> 00000012
# >> 00000013
# >> 00000014
# >> 00000015
```

Comment: excellent solution and the only one where the use of `times` is not misconstrued by updating another increment in the block  when `times` already provides one.

Comment: Sergio, I think you should have made it `25.times` to make it perfectly clear.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: i wanted to demonstrate that increment correctly overflows to the next position. 11.times would have sufficed, but I like 15 :)

Answer (score 1):

Meditate on this:

```
5.times { |i| i } # => 5
5.times.collect{ |i| i * 2 } # => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

The documentation for [`times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-times) shows it passes a value each time it iterates.

> Iterates the given block int times, passing in values from zero to int - 1.

Comment: `x.times.map` is a way of creating an array. I think his usage is more or less fine.

Comment: This does not answer the question should probably be a comment

Comment: seems everyone is missing the point that `times` will pipe in an incremental integer

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't easy to understand because it isn't clear what you want to accomplish. From what I understood you want to increment "00000000" > "00000001", etc.

For that you could use [String.rjust](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/rjust):

```
number_of_digits = 8
serial_number = 0 # Use an integer!!!

barcodes = batch_number.times.collect {
    serial_number += 1

    data = serial_number.to_s.rjust(number_of_digits, '0')

    # Do what you want with data
}
```

Best wishes!

**Update:** Sergio Tulentsev's answer is very handy too and even more elegant for this problem, but if you want more control over the serial number, this would be the way.

Comment: Since you are using times then predeclaring serial_number is not needed nor is incrementing it. `times` will pipe in an incremental integer with each loop.

Comment: I know that, but I don't want to change OP's code that much, just answer what he is needing.

Comment: What he is needing is to learn. You can catch fish with your bare hands but if I asked you how to fish I am certain this would not be your solution.

Comment: The essence of the question is not how he iterates, but how he zero-pads a String. And, by the way, this is just a way to proceed.

`serial_number` could be generated randomly or with any other formula. You're missing the point of the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky true thing that I need to learn :) but I am actually a girl and not a guy so you shouldn't jump to conclusions that quickly (that I am actually a guy).

Comment: @Jngai1297 very well although I did not jump I simply followed the preceding statement *" just answer what he is needing."* in order to maintain congruence

Comment: @Jngai1297: in absence of any information in your profile, one is free to assume whatever he wants about user Jngai1297 :)